# Non-existing MySql message error

Tags: java, mysql, eclipse

I have to build a Decision Support System, but dont have much experience in Java. So after I connected to MySql with Eclipse (with Connector/J) eclipse started to mess up my other projects. Now, when i try to run other projects in eclipse (that are not related to MySql, ex. Guessing Game) the following error message apperars:

```
Launch configuration DocsConnectionPropsHelper references non-existing project MySql connection test.
```

Can anyone help me to resolve this problem please?

UPDATE. it seems that when i press "RUN" elcipse is not running the project that im working with, but other

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your update indicates the issue is actually running the wrong project. To avoid that you may want to close projects you're not working on (right click them in package explorer and select close).

If you do need multiple projects open then when clicking the *run* icon (which defaults to re-run whatever was ran last among your open projects) make sure you have open in the editor window something that can be ran (and is from the project you want to run).

Then click the drop down arrow to the right of the icon. This will open up a small menu with options to change your build configurations or how it should run your program (i.e. as an application or on a server).

Comment: Thanks for respond, it worked only partially. THING IS THAT when i edit lines in project im working on and then execute it, it runes the code that i had BEFORE i edited, unless i save it. in other words, i need to SAVE the project and then run it even if i added only a single line to the code. Before i could write hundreds of lines, then just press run and everything was executed.

Comment: Go to Window -> Preferences -> Run/Debug -> Launching and make sure the "Save required dirty editors before launching" is set to Always

Answer (score 0):

To solve the problem:
-click right botton on the project package you want to work on (run)
-choose Run As
-choose Run Configurations...
-choose DocsConnectionPropsHelper - if in the Project box you see not correct title just remove it. Also remove anything what is in the Main Class box. 
-click Apply
-the best option is to close Eclipse and reopen it to make sure that all the settings were configured 
It worked for me. Hopefully it will work for you too.